# how to loop through subfolders and move certain type of files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, directory

I have a folder, and inside that folder I have many different folders with csv(excel) files in them. I want to write a pandas script such that it should loop through subfolders and move the files that has same format to one folder and also move the different format files to another folder.

The format I have in my subfolders are one that has string in the starting of its file name and other format has number as its starting and FYI some folders has both these type of files in them.
I am new to pandas so any help is appreciated.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This isn't a pandas question. What you want can be done in pythons standard library. Look into the os library (eg os.listdir()). You'll need to process the string files names to decide where that file belongs. Then have a quick Google of how to move files using python. There are many options